# React does not re-render updated array state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I have a simple array in below and I just change index of elements in array by a handler:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 5, val: "Italy" },
    { id: 2, val: "Germany" },
    { id: 3, val: "Brazil" },
    { id: 4, val: "Canada" }
]);
```

My Handler:

```
const handlePosition = (old_index, new_index) => {
    if (new_index >= items.length) {
      var k = new_index - items.length + 1;
      while (k--) {
        items.push(undefined);
      }
    }
    items.splice(new_index, 0, items.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);

    setItems(items);

    console.log(items);
};
```

I try to render the `items` array as follows:

```
<ul>
  {items.map((item, index) => (
    <li key={item.id}>
      {item.val}
        <button onClick={() => handlePosition(index, index + 1)}>DOWN</button>
        <button onClick={() => handlePosition(index, index - 1)}>UP</button>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Now, My array **changed properly and updates the state** but not re-render.

Here is a demo of my project in CodeSandBox: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/order-sort-numbers-mu2bi?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's because the **instance** of the `items` array is not changing.

Try this:

```
setItems([...items]);
```

That copies the array to a new identical array.  React will see that it's different and will re-render.

Comment: So helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I was stuck at this for 4 hours. Thanks

Comment: I now understand ...

Comment: My good god, the way I coded it this shouldn't in my logical sense have mattered BUT IT DID. thank you!