# React - update array in setState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This code should add item to array and thus make component rerender. In updateStateIncorrect I push new element to array and return the same array, in updateStateCorrect I create new array from old array elements, plus one new element, and return it. Why pushing element to the same array doesn't make component rerender? Why state is considered unchanged?

```html
function Component() {
  console.log("Component render");
  let [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const updateStateIncorrect = () => {
    setState((prev) => {
      // This doesn't work - component doesn't rerender.
      prev.push("New");
      return prev;
    })
  }
  const updateStateCorrect = () => {
    setState((prev) => {
      //This works
      return [...prev, "New"];
    })
  }
  return (
  <button 
    type="button" 
    onClick={() => {updateStateCorrect();updateStateIncorrect();}}>
  Click
  </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: That's expected. That's how React works. You need to create a new array so it detects changes.

Comment: I think this thread should be helpful.  Helped me out. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61896668/react-does-not-re-render-updated-array-state