# State does not update React Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I'm doing a rpg trait randomizer, where I have the traits in a array, and I can choose to random or add based on a select, but , whenever I click any of those buttons, the state on the select that should  show the array, doesn't get update, only if I open the add trait select.

In short, the problem is the array after a add is not showed in the display.

```
 return (
              <div 
                }} className="Traits">
                    <text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Traits</text>
                    <br /><button>Delete</button>

                    <select className="Traits-List"
                        multiple

                    >
                        {traitsList && (
                            traitsList.map((trait) => (
                                <option key={trait.label} value={trait.value}>{trait.label}</option>
                            )))}
                    </select>

                    <button onClick={(e) => { handleTraits() }}>Random</button><br />
                    <Select
                        placeholder={"traits"}
                        options={Traits}
                        menuPlacement="top"
                        styles={selectStyle}
                        onChange={handleTraitAddTemp} //?
                    ></Select>
                    <button onClick={() => { handleAddTrait(tempTrait) }}>Add</button>
                </div>
)
```

the handle functions

```
const [traitsList, setTraitsList] = useState([]);
    const [tempTrait, setTempTrait] = useState({});

     const handleTraitAddTemp = (e) => {
        console.log(e)
        setTempTrait(e);
    }

     function addTrait(Trait) { 
        const tempTraits = traitsList;
        console.log(traitsList)
        if (tempTraits && tempTraits.includes(Trait))
            return;

        tempTraits.push(Trait)
        console.log(tempTraits)
        return tempTraits 
    }

 function handleAddTrait(Trait) {
        let res = addTrait(Trait)
        setTraitsList(res);
    }

 function handleTraits() {
        let res = randomTraits()
        setTraitsList(res)
    }

function randomTraits() {
        const tempTraits = traitsList;
        let rng = randomNumber(1, 38)
        console.log(rng)
        console.log(tempTraits)
        console.log(traitsList)
        while ((tempTraits.length !== 0) && (tempTraits.includes(Traits[rng]))) {
            rng = randomNumber(1, 38)
            console.log(rng)
        }
        tempTraits.push(Traits[rng])
        console.log(tempTraits)
        return tempTraits
    }
```

[The left part i click the random button, the second i choose a trait in the menu then the random trait that i got is showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNJvy.png)

Comment: This exact question was asked earlier today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864282/react-update-array-in-setstate-hook

Comment: I guess so, I will try, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you do this `const tempTraits = traitsList;` replace with following.

```
const tempTraits = [...traitsList];
```

Comment: should i change in 
`setTraitsList(res)`

as well?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: i changed, and worked, thanks for the help!!