# computed array object not being set

Tags: vue.js, pusher

OK, so I am not sure how best to describe the problem. In the code below. There is a method called `leaveRoom(room)`. This code when invoked tells a system to vacate a room, then join array object 0 as the current room by using the mentioned method. However it isnt doing the line `this.setRoom(this.joinedRooms[0]);`

I can tell you there is an object 0 in the joinedRooms.

Any idea what the syntax error is?

```
methods: {
connect () {
        setRoom(room) {
            this.$store.dispatch(RoomTypes.CURRENT_ROOM, room);
            this.currentRoom = room;
            this.$emit('onSelectRoom', room);
        },
        leaveRoom(room) {
            this.room = this.currentRoom; 
            this.$store.dispatch(RoomTypes.LEAVE_ROOM, room.id);
            Echo.leave("chat." + this.currentRoom.id);
            this.setRoom(this.joinedRooms[0]);
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch(RoomTypes.GET_ROOMS);
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({ theme: "getTheme" }),
        joinedRooms() {
            return this.$store.state.rooms.joinedRooms;
        },
```

Comment: When you say it isn't doing that line, are you saying that line is not being invoked?  You've verified by logging?

Comment: I m saying that line isnt correct. it SEEMS base on a bunch of console logs I HAD in there it was passing that line. What isnt happening is joinedRooms[0] doesnt seem to be valid because currentRoom doesnt change.

Comment: Then it might be a similar issue to this React issue about not changing the instance of the array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61896734/2740650

Comment: Great Idea and you might be onto something but now I get "Uncaught TypeError: this.joinedRooms is not a function"

Comment: That's progress.  It's clearly something to do with the `this` pointer, but I'd suggest you update the code and ask specifically about that.  I actually don't know that much about Vue :)

Comment: well it gives me an error which is nice HAHA. what I am confused about is when I console.log every step of it including the array it all looks right and SHOULD work

Comment: Why don't u use mapState?

Comment: @AmaarrockzI could not figure out how to write it - suggestions?

Comment: dispatch is typically async. If your code to change rooms is async, then you have to wait for it before setting the room.

Comment: ^ This. "what I am confused about is when I console.log every step of it including the array it all looks right and SHOULD work " - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync . The question doesn't contain enough things that could affect this, there should be no place for guesswork. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.